# Fastest Inverse Square Root on iPhone (Swift, not ObjectC)

Tags: swift, sqrt

Refer to
[Fastest Inverse Square Root on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038641/fastest-inverse-square-root-on-iphone)

I need do a "Fastest Inverse Square Root" on iPhone iOS Swift, which is supposed to be faster than `1/sqrt(float)`.
How do I do it?

In embedded C programming, it is:

```
// Fast inverse square-root
// See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
func invSqrt(x: Float) -> Float {
    var halfx : Float = 0.5 * x
    var y : Float = x
    long i = *(long*)&y

    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1)
    y = *(float*)&i
    y = y * (1.5 - (halfx * y * y))

    return y
}
```

Comment: do you really, really need to? fast inverse square root is a really good fast approximation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only tricky part is how to do the forced conversions between floating
point numbers and integer types, and the easiest way is to use
`memcpy()`:

```
// Fast inverse square-root
// See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
func invSqrt(x: Float) -> Float {
    let halfx = 0.5 * x
    var y = x
    var i : Int32 = 0
    memcpy(&i, &y, 4)
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1)
    memcpy(&y, &i, 4)
    y = y * (1.5 - (halfx * y * y))
    return y
}
```

I made some performance tests on an iPhone 6s with 1.000.000 random
floating point numbers in the range 0 ... 1000, and it turned out
that `invSqrt(x)` is about 40% faster than `1.0/sqrt(x)`.

The maximal relative error was below 0.176%, confirming the bound in 
the Wikipedia article.

I also made a test with [`vvrsqrtf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vvrsqrtf) from the
Accelerate framework, but this was actually *slower* than 
calling `1.0/sqrt(x)`, at least when called with single floating
point numbers.

---

As of **Swift 3,** `memcpy()` can be replaced by the `bitPattern:`
method of `Float` and the corresponding constructor from `UInt32`:

```
func invSqrt(x: Float) -> Float {
    let halfx = 0.5 * x
    var i = x.bitPattern
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1)
    var y = Float(bitPattern: i)
    y = y * (1.5 - (halfx * y * y))
    return y
}
```